# How to display a result using Java EE

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee

My objective is to take 2 numbers and calculate either + , - , * , / using Java EE.I've already written some code , there is no errors , but i can't see the result . I used :

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
```

then :

```
  out.println(methodname(a,b));
```

Here is my Calculatrice.jsp file :

```
<form action="calculatrice" method="get" >
entrer a :<br>
<input name ="a" type="number" >
<br>
entrer b : <br>
<input type="number" name="b" >
<br>
</form>

<div>
<select name="operateur">

                <option value="Addition">Addition</option>
                <option value="Soustraction">Soustraction</option>
                <option value="Multiplication">Multiplication</option>
                <option value="Division">Division</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" value="Calculer" />
</div>
```

CalculatriceServlet class which extends HttpServlet :

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    doGet(request, response);
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    double a=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("a"));
    double b =Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("b"));
    String operateur =request.getParameter("operateur");
    Calculatrice c= new Calculatrice();
    if(operateur.equals("Addition")) {
        out.println(c.somme(a, b));

    }
    else if(operateur.equals("Soustraction")) {
        out.println(c.soustraction(a, b));
    }
    else if(operateur.equals("Multiplication")) {
        out.println(c.multiplication(a, b));
    }
    else {
        out.println(c.division(a, b));
    }
}
```

Calculatrice .java class contains implementation of the 4 methods .

Comment: In your form you have `method=“get”` , so you need to get those values in `doGet` method not `doPost` .

Comment: Yea i corrected it but it still doesn't work

Comment: Also, You need to close your `</form>` tag , after your submit buttom